# Unable to connect Nethereum with Infura

Tags: c#, ethereum

I'm new to Nethereum, and I'm reading from the documentation. I'm trying to connect to infura and get the balance of Ethereum Foundation account (As the documenation suggests: https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Nethereum.Workbooks/docs/nethereum-gettingstarted-infura/):

```
    public static async void run()
    {
        var web3 = new Web3("https://mainnet.infura.io");
        var balance = await web3.Eth.GetBalance.SendRequestAsync("0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe");
        Console.WriteLine(balance.ToString());
    }
```

This code stops when trying toapply SendRequestAsync with no furthur information, no exceptions, nothing at all. It just exited with code 0. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the documentation does not demonstrate a complete Console application.

This is the full example from the Nethereum playground http://playground.nethereum.com/csharp/id/1001

Note: we are moving away now from using interactive workbooks as the playground demonstrates full programs that can be easily copied and pasted.

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using Nethereum.Hex.HexConvertors.Extensions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Nethereum.Web3;

public class Program
{

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        // This sample shows how to connect to Ethereum mainnet using Infura
        // and check an account balance:

        // We first need to generate an instance of web3, using INFURA's mainnet url and 
        // our API key.
        // For this sample, we’ll use a special API key `7238211010344719ad14a89db874158c`,
        // but for your own project you’ll need your own key.
        var web3 = new Web3("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/7238211010344719ad14a89db874158c");

        // Check the balance of one of the accounts provisioned in our chain, to do that, 
        // we can execute the GetBalance request asynchronously:
        var balance = await web3.Eth.GetBalance.SendRequestAsync("0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae");
        Console.WriteLine("Balance of Ethereum Foundation's account: " + balance.Value);

    }

}
```